# cocos2d and chipmunk making bodies ignore gravity

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I am building a game for iPhone that has been in the works for about a month. I have different colored balls that fall from the top of the screen and a seal at the bottom that the player controls to try and catch them. As they are supposed to create a stack that grows with each new ball, similar to Scoops! on the app store currently. I have a body and shape that surronds each new ball sprite, they are affected by gravity. But the seal can not be affected by gravity, but I need it to have collsion detection to detect when the first ball and each supsequent ball hits it and is added to the stack. I have tried applyForce and applyed a force that counters gravity, this works until a ball collides with the seal, then it sinks off the screen. Can someone please help...  My code is farly long, but I can post the major parts for the object in question below:

```
-(void) AddSealSprite {

Seal = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Seal2Inverted.png"];
Seal.position = ccp(160, 0);
[self addChild: Seal z:1];
Seal.tag = 2;

 cpBody *SealBody = cpBodyNew(1, INFINITY);
 SealBody->p = cpv(160, 0);
cpSpaceAddBody(space, SealBody);
//Creates Seal shape

int NumberOfVerts = 4;
CGPoint SealVerts[] = {
    ccp(-60, -60),
    ccp(60, -60),
    ccp(60, 60),
    ccp(-60, 60), 
};

cpShape *SealShape = cpCircleShapeNew(SealBody, 100, cpvzero);
SealShape->e = 0.5;
SealShape->u = 1.0;
SealShape->data = Seal;
cpSpaceAddShape(space, SealShape);
// here is my gravity offset...

cpBodyApplyForce(SealBody, cpv(0, NumberOfBallsInStack * 200), cpvzero);

}
```

and the ball sprite method

```
-(void) addNewSpriteX: (float)x y:(float)y
{
int posx, posy;

CCSpriteBatchNode *batch = (CCSpriteBatchNode*) [self getChildByTag:kTagBatchNode];
posy = 0;

//New Random sprite code
switch (arc4random() % 5) {
    case 0:
        posx = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        posx = 60;
        break;
    case 2:
        posx = 120;
        break;
    case 3:
        posx = 180;
        break;
    case 4:
        posx = 240;
        break;
}

CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode:batch rect:CGRectMake(posx, posy, 60, 60)];
[batch addChild: sprite];

sprite.position = ccp(x,y);



int num = 4;

    CGPoint verts[] = {
    ccp(-30, -30),
    ccp(-30, 30),
    ccp( 30, 30),
    ccp( 30,-30),
};

cpBody *body = cpBodyNew(1.0f, cpMomentForPoly(1.0f, num, verts, CGPointZero));




// TIP:
// since v0.7.1 you can assign CGPoint to chipmunk instead of cpVect.
// cpVect == CGPoint

body->p = ccp(x, y);
cpSpaceAddBody(space, body);

cpShape* shape = cpPolyShapeNew(body, num, verts, CGPointZero);
shape->e = 0.5f; shape->u = 0.5f;
shape->data = sprite;
cpSpaceAddShape(space, shape);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you have is giving the seal infinite mass:

```
 cpBody *SealBody = cpBodyNew(INFINITY, INFINITY);
```

in this way, it will not be affected by gravity.

If you move the seal, you will need to call `cpHashResizeStaticHash` so that chipmunk can take it into account (static bodies are not added to the space as a way of optimization).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to bother reading through all your code and tell you something simple that will save you some time.

Since your using Cocos2d, make a ccTime function. [Here](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2130) is a tutorial on some other stuff and how to use ccTime.

In your ccTime, your sprite (the ball) needs to have it's y coordinate subtracted by a small amount (that amount depends upon how often ccTime is called). Short example:

```
@interface Ball : Sprite {
    float vx;
    float vy;
    float gravity;
    float bounce;
}

@property float vx;
@property float vy;

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt;

@end

@implementation Ball

@synthesize vx;
@synthesize vy;

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        gravity = -20.0;
        bounce = -0.7;
        Sprite *ball = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"Ball.png"];
        [self addChild:ball];
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
    float x = self.position.x;
    float y = self.position.y;
    vy += gravity; // You are essentially subtracting from the y axis of your sprite.
    x += vx * dt;
    y += vy * dt;

    self.position = ccp(x, y);
}

@end
```

This is not a legitimage program, but by looking at it you can see how it works.